# Applying styles based on jquery conditions

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a following html as follows:

```
    <div class="outerdiv">
      <div class="title">
      <div class="innerdiv">
        <div class="outerdiv">
         <div class="title">
         <div class="innerdiv">
          <div class="outerdiv">
           <div class="innerdiv>
<div class="outerdiv">
         <div class="title">
         <div class="innerdiv">
</div>
</div>
</div>
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>
```

I have to apply `"border-width:10px"` for all divs with `class = innerdiv` provided that "**outerdiv**" contains both "**title**" and "**innerdiv**"
.
My expected output is:

```
    <div class="outerdiv">
      <div class="title">
      <div class="innerdiv" style="border-width:10px">
        <div class="outerdiv">
         <div class="title">
         <div class="innerdiv" style="border-width:10px">
          <div class="outerdiv">
           <div class="innerdiv>
<div class="outerdiv">
         <div class="title">
         <div class="innerdiv" style="border-width:10px">
</div>
</div>
</div>
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>
```

I am trying this:

```
$(element).find(".outerdiv").not("[class="title"]).css("border-width","10px").
```

Edit: The number of divs are dynamic and not fixed in number

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use `:has` selector along with immediate child selector to target innerdiv element:

```
$('.outerdiv:has(.innerdiv):has(.title) > ,.title > .innerdiv ').css("border-width","10px");
```

**DEMO SNIPPET :**

```js
$(function(){
$('.outerdiv:has(.innerdiv):has(.title) > .title > .innerdiv ').css("border-width","100px").css('border' ,'1px solid grey')
}) ;
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="outerdiv">
  <div class="title">1
  <div class="innerdiv">2
    <div class="outerdiv">3
     <div class="title">4
     <div class="innerdiv">5
      <div class="outerdiv">6
       <div class="innerdiv">7
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with good css hierarchy just apply the styles to

```
 .outerdiv > .title > .innerdiv{
    css goes here
 }
```

and they will only affect divs in the hierarchy that you mentioned.

Answer (score -1):

Simply use:

```
$('.innerdiv').css('border-width','10px');
```

It will add border-width to all divs with class 'innerdiv'.